# Flutter - Best way to display and keep track of answers to dynamic questions

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter and Dart and hit a bit of a mental block.

From a JSON source, I'm able to download a list of questions that may require multiple choice, single choice, text, or a file upload type of answer (among others). The questions themselves are based on a selection the user makes beforehand and each question object has a value that tells me the type of question.

What's the best way to go about displaying the questions (one per screen--with forward and back buttons) and keeping track of the answers?  Should I create a class/widget for each type of question and save the answer and question ID in a map?  Would it be best to download the list of questions in the initState, then in the build method, get the question type, and using an if/else or switch statement, call the correct widget?

Just looking for the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to have a list of questions and another list of answers and an index of the current question. When clicking on the Next button, the index will be updated in a setState method, thus updating the screen. See this example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: Center(child: Questions())));
  }
}

class Questions extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QuestionsState createState() => _QuestionsState();
}

class _QuestionsState extends State<Questions> {
  var _indexQuestion = 0;

  var _questions = ['Question 1', 'Question 2'];
  var _answers = [
    ['Option 1', 'Option 2'],
    ['Opt 1', 'Opt 2'],
  ];

  _next() {
    setState(() {
      var lastIndex = _questions.length - 1;
      if (_indexQuestion < lastIndex) {
        _indexQuestion++;
      } else {
        // Is the last question
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(_questions[_indexQuestion]),
        for (var answer in _answers[_indexQuestion]) Text(answer),
        FlatButton(
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          child: Text('next'),
          onPressed: _next,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. That's the route I've taken so far and everything looks like it's working like it's supposed to. I just have a ton of refactoring to do because, in my opinion, I have too much business logic in my UI file.